# How to make JOGL OSGI bundles with native libraries loaded correctly?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, osgi, jogl, apache-karaf, bnd

I've been trying for days: http://forum.jogamp.org/JOGL-with-OSGi-td3773888.html#a4029139

This library has native dependencies embedded in jars. 
http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.jogamp.jogl|jogl-all|2.0-rc11|jar
http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.jogamp.gluegen|gluegen-rt|2.0-rc11|jar

Can you provide **detailed** instructions to make *osgified* versions of this?
It would be nice if you can use bnd http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/Bnd or bndtools http://bndtools.org/ in the process.

I've tried to make a gigantic bundle with everything embedded, but I cannot make karaf to find native libraries: I keep getting the error "no gluegen-rt in java.library.path"

I tried to make a fragment bundle but cannot make the pieces to match... Tried with bnd, tried with eclipse. Need help from more experienced people.

I have been trying to use that with Apache Karaf, so it would be excellent if you can make that work with Karaf 2.3.1
If you know how to do it with Eclipse RCP 4.2 then please help!

Comment: I don't have the time to provide *detailed* instructions. Please show what you've got so far... the .bnd file in particular, and what error(s) it produces (and when those errors occur, e.g. during build or run)

Comment: Thanks for replying @NeilBartlett. I followed this tutorial http://wadeawalker.wordpress.com/2010/10/09/tutorial-a-cross-platform-workbench-program-using-java-opengl-and-eclipse/ and learned how to make a fragment bundle with Eclipse 3.8 (first I tried with 4.2, but couldn't run the main project). However, at this moment, the same bundles don't work with Karaf (it's 2:10 am for me and I'm exhausted). Maybe I will use Eclipse. However, I am developing mostly with Scala and don't know if I will have more issues... Last time I tried I had this issue http://bit.ly/176u95V

Answer (score 0):

First of all this isn't a Karaf specific issue, you might want to start with a unit test first, using pax exam. For your issue you need to make sure the native libs don't have dependencies to each other.
You might be interested in the following links.

http://robertvarttinen.blogspot.de/2008/12/bundle-nativecode-in-osgi-manifest.html
http://holistictendencies.wordpress.com/2011/03/28/bundle-nativecode-using-platform-specific-dlls-from-osgi/
[Load DLL (using JNA) inside an OSGi bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375550/load-dll-using-jna-inside-an-osgi-bundle)

Comment: Thank you very much for the guidance. This weekend I'll be really busy (and tired) but will come back as soon as possible. At least I could do it with Eclipse...

Comment: If it works with a pure eclipse scenario it should work with Karaf also. You might share your current success with us at github. And ask for some guidance at the Karaf users mailing list.